# chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow works on Windows, but not Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome-extension, auth0, google-chrome-os

I have a chrome extension that requires users login.  I've been successfully able to login for the past month or so on both Windows and Chrome OS.

However today (5/5/2020) when I try to login on Chrome OS it fails.  It still works on Chrome (version 81.0.4044.138) on Windows--just not Chrome OS.

The difference from what I can tell, is the callback to [chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow) succeeds and passes a responseUrl on Windows, but on Chrome OS the responseUrl is undefined.

Because it works on Windows, and it's using the same backend for both, this leads me to believe it's not a backend issue but potentially something with Chrome OS.

Edit:  I can further add that the parameters (url and interactive) are both identical between windows and chrome os.

Comment: Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) this is off-topic for StackOverflow. You can probably report it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: I don't think it's so black and white.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  Certainly doesn't fit the category of "best" question or "most" on topic.  Regardless, I'm not trying to be the SO police or a rebel.

Comment: It's just unclear to me what help you're expecting from people by posting a question without code. In the current form this looks clearly like a bug in Chrome. Bugs should be reported on a bug tracker and thus they will be found by people searching for the symptoms. Currently this question+answer pair looks like a pointless duplicate of a bug tracker.

Comment: Also, will you delete this when the bug gets fixed or will it forever stay here for no good?

Comment: I wouldn't delete it.  Its valuable as long as chrome os 81 can exist on any chromebook.

Comment: A bug report on the official bug tracker is sufficient. This q+a doesn't add any value.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Chrome OS 81 has a bug.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1077504